# Extracting Pirmary Key columns from pbit file

Tags: json, powerbi, powerquery

In the pbit file of Power BI model, in the `DataModelSchema` json section, in tables and columns there is property "isKey". I assume it emerges when we create 1->∞ relationships. Nevertheless, the TRUE value of that column does not lead us to a real Primary Key column name, but to some system PK column with name i.e., `RowNumber-2662979B-1795-4F74-8F37-6A1BA8059B61` which has the same name across all PK columns in all tables. Strange. How to link TRUE isKey columns with the names of their non-system counterparts?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you get your set of keys from the relationships section. The section below shows a relationship from Table A[Column1] to table B[Column1] and both columns are listed as keys (to support the relationship of course) elsewhere in the .pbit.

```
  "relationships": [
      {
        "name": "ef91814a-eb7a-457a-a6cf-8644bee5d2d8",
        "fromTable": "B",
        "fromColumn": "Column1",
        "toTable": "A",
        "toColumn": "Column1",
        "state": "ready"
      }
    ],
```